# excel - protect a sheet always?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

To me, it seems like the way to edit a protected sheet is unprotect it and type some stuff in and then protect it again before sending it to someone else. What if a user forgets protecting it before sending it again? Is there a way I can always protect it?

Comment: You could add a macro to the Save event that forces the sheet to be protected. That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: @RandolphWest Macro-approach was what I was thinking too.

Comment: My Excel macro knowledge is so rusty, I won't even try to answer this question, but that's the way I'd go about it.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the macro recorder to incorporate the elements you want to make sure are protected.
@Randolph West  is probably right in the approach

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveWorkbook.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Protect Structure:=True, Windows:=True
End Sub
```